# C# StackPanel: Old Items Remain After Updating Values

Tags: c#, button, textblock, stackpanel

Hey there StackOverflow,

I am having an issue with a certain portion of my Windows Store app. This is initially what is displayed...
[image: Initialized]

and this is what happens when the button is clicked
[image: Show More Clicked]

As you can see, the show more button and the original string is still present. I have tried making the "Show More" button update the TextBlock to a "" value and the "Show More" button is still there and clickable. I have also tried clearing the StackPanel and re-adding the items to no avail.

Here is the code I used to do this:

```
    private async void Description_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await wiki;
        if (wiki.Result.ContainsKey("real_name"))
        {
            TeamInfoTitle.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            TeamDescription.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            PopulateInfo(Description);
        }
        else if(wiki.Result.ContainsKey("current_members"))
        {
            CharacterInfoTitle.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            Description.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            PopulateInfo(TeamDescription);
        }
    }        
void expand_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HyperlinkButton button = (HyperlinkButton)sender;
        button.Content = "Show Less";
        button.Click -= expand_Click;
        button.Click += shrink_Click;
        TextBlock text = (TextBlock)button.Tag;
        text.Text = (string)text.Tag;
    }

    void shrink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HyperlinkButton button = (HyperlinkButton)sender;
        button.Content = "Show More";
        button.Click -= shrink_Click;
        button.Click += expand_Click;
        TextBlock text = (TextBlock)button.Tag;
        string item = (string)text.Tag;
        text.Text = item.Substring(0, item.LastIndexOf(" ", 150, 15)) + "...";
    }

    private void PopulateInfo(Grid desc)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < desc.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
        {
            string value;
            if (wiki.Result.TryGetValue((desc.Children[i] as TextBlock).Name, out value))
            {
                FrameworkElement now = new TextBlock() { Text = value, FontSize = 24, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap };
                if (value.Length > 200)
                {
                    TextBlock text = (TextBlock)now;
                    HyperlinkButton expand = new HyperlinkButton() { Content = "Show More", HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Right, VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Bottom };
                    expand.Tag = text;
                    expand.Click += expand_Click;
                    StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
                    text.Tag = value;
                    text.Text = value.Substring(0, value.LastIndexOf(" ", 150)) + "...";
                    stack.Children.Add(text);
                    stack.Children.Add(expand);
                    now = stack;
                }
                Grid.SetRow(now, i);
                Grid.SetColumn(now, 1);
                now.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 10);
                desc.Children.Add(now);
            }
            else
                desc.Children[i].Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Note: Description and TeamDescription are Grids defined in the XAML.

Comment: Are you sure `PopulateInfo` is run only once? You should post a bigger part of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the XAML code was triggering the loaded event twice, thanks swistak for putting me on the right track!